# systemd.resolved wont start - stale file handle

Tags: 20.04, systemd-resolved, systemd-networkd

I was getting issues with resolving any dns ive checked network settings without problem. Then ive realize that systemd-resolved wasnt started. Can you help me with the issue?

What ive tried
checked service configiration from different machine didnt find anything wrong

on different post i found that helped changing strict parameter to full same issue

updated all packages

ubuntu 20.04 lts

logs

```
    root@de00srvapp732r1:/run/systemd/unit-root# sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
Job for systemd-resolved.service failed.
See "systemctl status systemd-resolved.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@de00srvapp732r1:/run/systemd/unit-root# sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-11-27 17:46:48 CET; 11s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
    Process: 2990134 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
   Main PID: 2990134 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)

Nov 27 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 27 17:46:48 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Nov 27 17:46:48 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 27 17:46:48  systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 27 17:46:48 dsystemd[1]: Failed to start Network Name Resolution.



systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Starting Network Name Resolution...
systemd-resolved.service: Failed to set up mount namespacing: /run/systemd/unit-root/home: Stale file handle
systemd-resolved.service: Failed at step NAMESPACE spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved: Stale file handle
systemd-resolved.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE
systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Stopped Network Name Resolution.
systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd-resolved.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start Network Name Resolution.
```